# Как в регулярном выражении написать "или"?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Имеем строку `url = 'http://site.loc/?a=1&search=abcdf';`
и регулярное выражение `re = /\&search\=.*?(?=\&)/g;`

Только оно срабатывает, если находит за искомым словом символ `&`.
Если же его нет, то выражение не срабатывает.

Как мне исправить регулярное выражение, что бы оно выполнялось или до `&` или до конца строки `$`?

Comment: исправьте опечатку в url, а то у меня в голове ваша регулярка никогда не срабатывала  =)

Comment: Исправил. Спасибо

Comment: а теперь еще раз вглядитесь =)

Comment: Заметил и исправил)

Comment: Но код по прежнему не работает

Comment: потомучто, он не верный. Вам же уже написали ответ =)

Comment: @LexHobbit Код у меня работает, но если нету &(конец строки), то код не срабатывает.

Comment: Здесь вообще не нужно использовать регулярные выражения. Найдите в нужном вам языке функцию для разбора URL и URL Query.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо за совет, но я бы все равно не успокоился бы пока не нашел правильное решение на регулярном выражении

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте. Символ | - это или, также для таких поисков применяется [^&]+ - любые количеством больше 1, кроме &

```js
console.log('http://site.loc/?search=abcdf&a=1'.match(/(\?|&)search=([^&]+)/)[2])
```

Comment: Не то. Совсем не туда. Я в примере указал url, он должен срабатывать до знака &. а если он отсутствует, то до конца строки

Comment: `(\?|&)` я бы записал как `[?&]`. Короче, шустрее.

Comment: @vKs а что по вашему происходит в моей регулярке? Именно это - до знака & , или конец строки

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, а ваш код сработает, если убрать &a=1?

Comment: @vKs таки проверьте, F12 - и выполняйте на здоровье мой код) Сработает.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр да, ваш код тоже работает. Спасибо, я его сразу не понял

Answer (score 2):

```js
r = /[?&]search=([^&]+)/;
console.log('http://site.loc/?search=abcdf&a=1'.match(r)[1]);
console.log('http://site.loc/?search=abcdf'.match(r)[1]);
console.log('http://site.loc/?b=1&search=abcdf'.match(r)[1]);
console.log('http://site.loc/?b=1&search=abcdf&a=1'.match(r)[1]);

// если доработать именно ваш код...
r = /&search=(.*)(?=&)*/;
//                    ^
console.log('http://site.loc/?b=1&search=abcdf'.match(r)[1]);
```

Квантификаторы можно указывать и для групп.

Comment: Код r = /&search=(.*)(?=&)*/; мягко говоря, рубит все. Без разбора

Comment: Конечно, это ведь иллюстрация к использованию квантификаторов.

Answer (score 1):

Я понимаю, что разбор `url` был бы приемлем, но на данный момент мне нужно было регулярное выражение, которое сделало бы то, что от него требуется.

Сегодня методом изучения нашел правильное решение:

`re = /&search\=((.*?)(?=&)|(.*))/g;` ищет от `&search=` до следующего `&`, а если не находит, то до конца строки. Вот это мне нужно было сделать.

Comment: Из исходного вопроса это невозможно понять.